# Dynamically check javascript value after database update

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a dynamically generated and self updating form in ASP.NET MVC using javavascript, Jquery, JSON/Ajax calls.

Here is how I set up my view code from the controller. I loop through all available controls from the controller:

```
<ul>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "WebMan", FormMethod.Post)) { 
            foreach (var row in Model.controls)
            {
                    <li>
                        <label>@row.Name</label>
                        @if (row.ControlType == "STRING" || row.ControlType == COMMENT")
                        {
                            <input type="text" name="@row.Name" id="@row.NameID" value="@row.Value" data-original-value="@row.Value" class="form-control data-field" style="width: 300px"/>
                        }
                        else if (row.ControlType == "DDL")
                        {

                            <select name="@row.Name" id="@row.NameID" class="form-control data-field" value="@row.Value" data-original-value="@row.Value" style="width: 300px">
                                @foreach (var o in row.Options)
                                {
                                    <option value="@o.Value">@o.Text</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        } 
                    </li>
            }
                <button type="submit">Update</button>
          }
        </ul>
```

(notice that I set the value to the value from the database and I also set the “data-original-value” to the value from the database as well)
I am using the “data-original-value” to check to see if the value has changed later.

I also set up a javascript timer that executes every 5 seconds. This timer is meant to “update” the page. (code for timer below)

```
 var interval = setInterval(function () { Update(); }, 10000);
```

When the timer executes, we loop through each control in the “data-field” class. This allows me to check each dynamically generated control.

Basically, If a user has edited a control, I DO NOT want to update that control, I want to ignore it. I only want to update that specific control if a user has not changed the value. When a user changes the value, the current value != orig value (Data-original-value), so we set the field to yellow and ignore the database update code.

```
function Update() {
    UpdateControls();        
}
function UpdateControls() {

    $(".data-field").each(function () {
        var nameAttr = $(this).attr('name');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        var val = document.getElementById(id).value;
   
        var origVal = $(this).data("original-value");
        
    
        if (origVal == val) {
           //user did not change control, update from database
            var url = "/WebMan/UpdateControlsFromDB/";
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { name: nameAttr },
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {

        document.getElementById(id).setAttribute("data-original-value", data);
                        
        document.getElementById(id).value = data;
                       
                      
                        
                       
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("Issue updating the page controls from database");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            
            document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
           //user changed control, do not update control and change color
        }

    });
}
```

If no change, this ajax method in my controller is called:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateControlsFromDB(string name)
    {
        var curValue= db.Setup.Where(x => x.Name == name).Select(x =>Value).FirstOrDefault();

        return Json(curValue);
    }
```

The code works correctly if a user modifies the field. It senses that the user modifies the code, and changes the field yellow.

The part that does not work correctly, is if the database updates the field. When the database first updates the field, it looks great. We set the “data-original-field” value to the value as well, to tell our code that is should not turn yellow and the user has not modified it.

But after another update, “value” and “original-value” do not match. The code document.getElementById(id).value somehow gets the OLD version of the control. It does not get the current value. So then on next loop, the values don’t match and we stop updating from DB and the control turns yellow.

My issue is that my code senses that the control value changed (database update) and turns it yellow, when I only want to turn the control yellow when a USER has changed the value in the control.

I only want to change the control and prevent updating from DB when the control has been modified by the user.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: When you assign `setAttribute` and `.value` inside success function of ajax are they assigning correct value to your inputs ? Did you check that by inspecting html generated ?

Comment: Inspecting the element shows the .setAttribute does change the "original-value" but the "value" of the input is incorrect... The control displays the new correct value but upon inspection the actual HTML has the incorrect value. Good catch. Any ideas on how to fix this or why this could happen?

Comment: you are saying `control displays the new correct value..` and when inspect it shows incorrect value .This can happen because you  are calling same function every 5 sec so it might not have update previous data and go to new data ..